# Expectation value of waiting time

Tags: probability, expected-value

The two colleagues $X$ and $Y$ agreed to meet between $0$ pm and $1$ pm. The time of their arrivals in this interval are independent and they are uniformly distributed. How is expectation of waiting the first to the second (or mean waiting time the first to the second)?

I understand that the joint density is
\begin{align*}
f(x,y)=\begin{cases}1 &\text{ if } (x,y)^\top\in\left<0,1\right>\times\left<0,1\right>,\\
0 &\text{ otherwise}.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Also I uderstand that probability that $X$ will be waiting to $Y$ is $P(X<Y)$. Is it some important that the first will be waiting to the second (not only that $X$ will be waiting to $Y$ but also can happen that $Y$ will be waiting to the $X$)? Honestly, I do not know why I am quite confused about this example.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT:** You already have the joint density, which is $1$ on the square $[0, 1] \times [0, 1]$ (and $0$ elsewhere). To find the expected value of any variable, you just need to integrate that function defining that variable against the density function (this is sometimes referred to as the ["Law of the Unconscious Statistician"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician)). In this case, your variable is $|X - Y|$, which will measure the gap between the two arrival times and count the gap as positive no matter who arrives first. This means that your task is to compute
$$\mathbb E \left| X - Y \right| = \int_0^1 \int_0^1 |x - y| \cdot 1 \, \textrm d y \, \textrm d x.$$

Comment: Thank you very much. Now it is so clear for me.